# Magento extend inventory form

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, inventory

I'd like to add two extra fields to the inventory tab when adding/editing a product. I find lot's of tutorials on how to add a new tab or create product attributes, but that's not what I'm looking for. How can I add those extra fields.

I suppose I should add a block to the config.xml and create the block. But I can figure out what settings I should use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [add attribute in product information -> Inventory tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079549/add-attribute-in-product-information-inventory-tab)

Comment: In the marked duplicate, look at the highest rated answer, no the answer chosen ;)